# How to build business object with spring repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm trying to work with a spring CrudRepository.
In my current implementation this repository does not store the business object itself, which I want to work with in the application. But rather only specific parts are stored, that are required to restore my business object. After this restore is complete, this data is no longer needed. At least not by any other class within the project. This is why I want to avoid passing unnecessary data around the whole project.

Now let's say my model looks something like this:

```java
interface Car {
    // This is my business object I want to work with
}


@Entity
class CarParts {
    // This data is stored in the DB and required to re-construct the business object.
    PartA a;
    PartA b;
    Long id;
}


interface CarFactory {
    Car createCar(CarParts parts);
}
```

As you can see, the CarParts are stored into the persistence layer but that's not the object I want to work with. The car itself is the object I need. This can be obtained by using the factory class. Now obviously I do not want to call the factory manually each time I use the CrudRepository. Instead I'd like this to happen automatically. Best case would be to get an instance of the Car class from the Repository. Do I have to add another abstraction layer, which will perform this conversion or is there maybe another (spring) solution available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a standard [multi-layered architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Common_layers), the *data access layer* (a.k.a. *persistence layer*) is responsible for storing/retrieving from database.

If you want the data in a different form, that would be the responsibility of the *business layer* (aka *business logic layer* aka *domain layer*), which is where **business rules** for how to construct a `Car` from `CarParts` would belong.

No, it is not another layer, it is part of the *business logic layer*.

Comment: I see, thanks for enlightening me. But isn't it quite common for the repository to actually return a business object? That's what I saw in all these guides about persistence.

Comment: @Brainsucker92 The data access layer should abstract anything that has to do with storing the data, e.g. you should be able to replace the data access layer with another implementation that stores the data in text files, or one that communicates with a web service to store the data. As such, Entity classes shouldn't be seen outside the data access layer, which is why Entity data to moved to/from DTO objects in the data access layer. --- However, your design of storing a `Car` as `CarParts` is a business decision, not a technical storage decision, so that mapping belongs in the business layer.